# Sending large file of 10 TB size from hdfs to S3 using Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-nifi, large-files

I have a flat file with 10TB in size in HDFS. I need to write data to Kafka and later save into Amazon S3. I am looking for different approaches for this task. Based on previous questions that are asked, I understood that it can be done by Nifi or Spark. However, I am not clear on how it can be implemented.

Comment: It is not really clear what you want to do... you want to use nifi to get the 10TB file from HDFS and then write the data to Kafka? or you already have data in Kafka and you want to read it with NiFi and batch it together and write large files to HDFS/S3 ?

Comment: I updated the question. Could you please check it now?

Comment: NiFi has processors PublishKafka and ConsumeKafka and it has a processor for writing to S3 called PutS3Object

Answer (score 2):

@icyanide This is a very basic Nifi Use case you are describing.  It should work great.  You can also do it with spark, but I would prefer NIFI personally because its easy to program without writing any code.

Flow 1:  List/FetchHDFS -> PublishKafka

Flow 2:  ConsumeKafka -> putS3

Flow 3:  List/FetchHDFS ->PublishKafka -> PutS3

Flow 4:  List/FetchHDFS -> PutS3 -> PublishKafka -> even more downstream processing of contents, etc..

One bit of warning, the large 10tb file is going to be a processing work load to get it, copy it to s3, and/or do something with the contents.  Make your nifi nodes big spec, and cluster more than one node if you can and you expect to have multiple 10tb files processing in parallel.  If you need the data in Kafka for separate downstream events, like for example metadata with s3 url, I would go HDFS -> S3 directly -> PublishKafka (#4).

Comment: how can it be done on spark? if we load all 10tb into spark and publish it to kafka, would it happen in a go? I am also looking for an option to restrict it to 2-3 TB per day.